# How do I troubleshoot an LSI HBA card that is not recognized as a controller `storcli`?

Tags: ubuntu, nas, storage, sas, storcli

first time posting in here, I hope I'm not off-topic.

I am trying to set up a Supermicro CSE-826 chassis, but with an ASRock J4005B-ITX board and an LSI SAS 9207-4i4e card instead of an officially Supermicro-supported system.
The backplane in the system is a Supermicro BPN-SAS3-826EL1 (just in case that matters for the following - it probably doesn't...). I currently have 4 SAS HDDs installed in the chassis.

My problem is the following: I simply want to get the card to work as a HBA in JBOD mode, using Ubuntu 20.04 server (headless).

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 to a separate SATA SSD directly connected to the motherboard (i.e. I'm not booting off the SAS array). I installed `storcli` (assuming that's the right tool for setting up the HBA, please correct me if I'm already off track here) and my goal is to set it to JBOD mode so I can just manually manage the attached disks.

Running `lsblk` currently does not show me any of the four HDDs installed on the backplane:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2074
loop1    7:1    0  69.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19188
loop2    7:2    0  70.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21029
loop3    7:3    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1944
loop4    7:4    0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12398
loop5    7:5    0  31.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/10707
sdd      8:48   0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sdd1   8:49   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdd2   8:50   0   238G  0 part /
```

And running `storcli` does not show me the LSI controller:

```
$ sudo /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 show all
CLI Version = 007.1705.0000.0000 Mar 31, 2021
Operating system = Linux 5.4.0-80-generic
Status Code = 0
Status = Success
Description = None

Number of Controllers = 0
Host Name = malacca
Operating System  = Linux 5.4.0-80-generic
StoreLib IT Version = 07.1703.0200.0000
StoreLib IR3 Version = 16.14-0

$ sudo /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0 show
CLI Version = 007.1705.0000.0000 Mar 31, 2021
Operating system = Linux 5.4.0-80-generic
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = Controller 0 not found
```

The HBA card does show up when I query `lspci`, though:

```
$ lspci | grep LSI
01:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: Broadcom / LSI SAS2308 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 (rev 05)
```

These are the relevant modules that are loaded (I assume - am I missing any specific ones?):

```
$ lsmod | grep sas
mpt3sas               274432  0
raid_class             16384  1 mpt3sas
scsi_transport_sas     36864  2 ses,mpt3sas
$ lsmod | grep mega
megaraid               45056  0
```

I'm not finding any good troubleshooting / install guides from Broadcom or LSI, maybe I'm just looking in the wrong place but anything I can find is just instructions on how to configure an installed, and working, system.

How do I get `storcli` to properly recognize my LSI card and subsequently get my HDDs to show up in `/dev/sd*`? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flash the controller to IT mode. Look it up as firmware flashing to IT mode. Than it will act as a HBA. By default it is a RAID controller.

Comment: How does that explain that it's finding zero controllers, isn't storcli also the tool to manage RAID controllers? Also, SAS 9207 is sold as an HBA with IT firmware, if it had IR firmware on it it would be a SAS 9217 (see page 2 of [this document](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/redx/tools/mb_download.php/mid.y0808488c914d3ba0/Frequently_Asked_Questions_HBA_20121010.pdf)).

Comment: Does it show up on lspci? Does it show preboot (BIOS OPROM) info like the list of HDDs connected to it?